# Join 2 tables over 2 columns in django

Tags: mysql, django, database, django-models

I have a database imported from mysql in models.py like :

```
class Sig(models.Model):
id = models.IntegerField(db_column='Id', primary_key=True)
proportion = models.FloatField(db_column='Prop', blank=True, null=True)
marine_area = models.CharField(db_column='Marine_Area', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
habitat = models.CharField(db_column='Habitat', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
```

This one doesn't have any coordinates associated. The coordinates are in another table :

```
class Coord(models.Model):
id = models.IntegerField(db_column='Id', primary_key=True)
marine_area = models.CharField(db_column='Marine_Area', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
habitat = models.CharField(db_column='Habitat', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
latitude = models.FloatField(db_column='Latitude', blank=True, null=True)
longitude = models.FloatField(db_column='Longitude', blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to visualized my proportions according to their coordinates (latitude and longitude).
However, each localisation is define with a marine area and an habitat (each marine area has 3 habitats)

[for ex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfACC.png)

So how can I create a new column with the concatenation of marine area and habitat to be able to join my two tables ?

or is there any other solution to join my two tables ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

So not exactly sure what you mean when you say its imported, so this may not be what you are looking for:

My solution would be to turn `marine_area` and `habitat` into models of their own (or you could make them one model if that works best for your use-case) and use a ForeignKey relation ship from the two models you provided. So for example you might have the following models:

```py
class Habitat(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    # ... other data

class MarineArea(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    habitats = models.ManyToManyField(Habitat, related_name="marine_areas")
    # ... other data

class Sig(models.Model):
    proportion = models.FloatField(db_column='Prop', blank=True, null=True)
    marine_area = models.ForeignKeyField(MarineArea, related_name="sigs")
    habitat = models.ForeignKeyField(Habitat, related_name="sigs")

class Coord(models.Model):
    marine_area = models.ForeignKeyField(MarineArea, relate_name="coords")
    habitat = models.ForeignKeyField(Habitat, related_name="coords")
    latitude = models.FloatField(db_column='Latitude', blank=True, null=True)
    longitude = models.FloatField(db_column='Longitude', blank=True, null=True)
```

This allows you to say `marine_area.habitats.all()` and get a list of all habitats for that marine area, or `habitat.marine_areas.all()` to get a list of all marine areas with that habitat type. You then use ForeignKeys to relate the `Sig` and `Coord` back to the `Habitat` and `MarineArea` model.

If you don't have this much control over the data, then you might be best served using a raw query.

Comment: OP stated that he already has a MySQL DB that they’re using these models with…

Comment: Yeah, thats why I edited the comment. Depending on usecase it would still technically be possible to break things up. Otherwise (as I added at the end) a raw query would be their best option afaik.

Comment: Yup, there’s the `.extra` also, but that’s really not recommended so.. :shrug:

Comment: I can have this control on my data but it would be too much because I have like 50 tables concerned by this issue ...

Comment: I tried a query in views.py : new_col = SigMpaCoord.objects.annotate(full_name = Concat('marine_area', Value(' '), 'habitat')) --> but I only have it on my terminal, I can't get it to join the tables after

Comment: Yeah, if you don't want to refactor the models, then you will want to look into using raw SQL queries. Here is how to do them from django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/sql/